# convert file path returned from Directory in to tilde

Tags: c#, asp.net, directory

I am using Directory.Enumeratefiles to get the path some images stored in a particular directory.

The directory.enumeratefiles method returns the path as "D:\Gallery\Test\1.jpg"

Anyway when I bind it to a image in a repeater the path turns into "D:\Gallery\Test\1.jpg", but the image doesnt display in the page.

I just want to know whether the path can be converted to tilde (~) when binding.

Comment: what is the src attribute of the image in html code? is the location is accessible from browser? try to move images to subfolder of your project like images

Comment: You want to shorten the file path by using tilde(~) ?

Comment: Is "D:\Gallery\Test\" a Virtual Directory?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to map the real paths to virtual paths yourself; basically the reverse of `Server.MapPath`.

The easiest way to do this is to run something like this:

```
var root = Server.MapPath("~");
var relative = realPath.Replace(root, "~").Replace("\\", "/");
```